# How to monitor long running jobs in hadoop cluster ?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How to monitor long running jobs in hadoop cluster ? which all possibilities are there for long running job? and how to overcome that?

Comment: could you tell me what kind of job are you running?

Comment: e.g hive complex queries

Comment: using mapper and reducer logs you can able to identify the issue

Comment: For each query we will have URL

Comment: Using that URL we can monitor the hive jobs

Comment: if you partitioned the table, then it may solve you problem

Comment: can you send me your hive query's

Comment: Thanks.. actually Its an interview question..

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor all the jobs that are running on a YARN cluster by tracking the job URL that you will get after submitting the job.

You can monitor your Hive job status also using resource manager web UI. Visit localhost:8088, here you can see the list of all jobs that are submitted to the YARN cluster in that session.

There are some tips that can be followed to optimize your Hive queries. You can refer [to this blog](https://acadgild.com/blog/tips-to-optimize-your-hive-queries/) for more details on optimizing your hive queries.

Comment: thanks for the response.. can you tell the possible reasons for long running jobs? and how to overcome that? Is it good practice to kill a job and rerun it?

Comment: There can be a lot of reasons for long running jobs. The size of the data and if your hive query involves a number of joins and on your hardware also.